# How can I retrieve a route's model() when writing a test?

Tags: testing, ember.js

I have a route that has its own model, which does not come from the Ember store (let's say it can come from "anywhere" for the sake of this question).

```
  model() {
    return RSVP.hash({
      value: someCall()
    });
  }
```

`this.owner.lookup('route:routeName').model()` does not seem to work, neither does `this.owner.lookup('controller:controllerName').get('model.X')` or any of the other things I've tried.

Nor does it seem to be mentioned at https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/testing/testing-routes/

How would you retrieve a route's model in a test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ember router doesn't appear to have any kind of public interface to get the model according to the official docs (https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/EmberRouter). It can access the model function internally though. This feels a bit hackish, but I was able to get it to work:

Router:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { hash } from 'rsvp';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return hash({
      value: 'wibble'
    });
  },

  getMyModel: function() {
    return this.get('model')();
  }
});
```

Router test:

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupTest } from 'ember-qunit';

module('Unit | Route | test', function(hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks);

  test('do something with the router model...', function(assert) {
    let route = this.owner.lookup('route:test');
    assert.ok(route);

    route.getMyModel().then(function(model) {
      console.log(model);
      assert.equal(model.value, 'wibble');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It works. However, one follow-up question: `this` appears to be undefined inside `model()`, but it is defined inside `getMyModel()`. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: `this` is usually defined in model(). For example, to use the Ember Data store to fetch data, you might use the following code: `return this.get('store').findAll('thing');` Not sure what issue you're hitting there.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with:

```
route.get('model')()
```